# IHS webserver connecting to websphere application server

Tags: plugins, webserver, websphere, websphere-7, ibmhttpserver

I have one applicaion server having multiple nodes. When I am connecting the application through application server, it is working fine. But when I am connecting the application through webserver, it is not working for one node and for all other nodes it works.

What would be the possible cause. I have re-configured the plugin for that particular node many a times. no luck.

I see below logs in plugin log (date may change):

```
*[Mon Aug 10 11:53:50 2009] 00001dec 00001e04 - ERROR: ws_common: websphereGetStream: Failed to connect to app server on host 'windowsinternal.pt', OS err=78
[Mon Aug 10 11:53:51 2009] 00001dec 00001e04 - ERROR: ws_common: websphereGetStream: Failed to connect to app server on host 'windowsinternal.pt', OS err=78
[Mon Aug 10 11:53:51 2009] 00001dec 00001e04 - ERROR: ws_common: websphereExecute: Failed to create the stream
[Mon Aug 10 11:53:51 2009] 00001dec 00001e04 - ERROR: ws_common: websphereHandleRequest: Failed to execute the transaction to 'windowsinternalNode01_server1'on host 'windowsinternal.pt'; will try another one
[Mon Aug 10 11:53:51 2009] 00001dec 00001e04 - ERROR: ws_common: websphereWriteRequestReadResponse: Failed to find an app server to handle this request
[Mon Aug 10 11:53:51 2009] 00001dec 00001e04 - ERROR: ESI: getResponse: failed to get response: rc = 2
[Mon Aug 10 11:53:51 2009] 00001dec 00001e04 - ERROR: ws_common: websphereHandleRequest: Failed to handle request
[Mon Aug 10 11:53:52 2009] 00001dec 000015b4 - ERROR: ws_common: websphereGetStream: Failed to connect to app server on host 'windowsinternal.pt', OS err=78*
```

Comment: Verify that you can connect to that server directly from the browser using web container port. Check also that you can connect from web server host to app server host for example using telnet. Verify that `windowsinternal.pt` name resolves on your webserver host.

Comment: I can access the server directly using default host secure/non-secure port
also, i am able to connect other nodes(which are on the same application server) through webserver
not sure, why the issue is with a particular node

Comment: Directly from the browser or from web server host? You have to ssh/rdp to web server and try access WAS from there.

Comment: From the browser. could you please connect to me through hangout (nitesh.spj@gmail.com) so that we can discuss more on this

Comment: What OS does the webserver run on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue was resolved. There was firewall issue with the default secure port. I just changed the port and it worked.